# When select dropdown directive for submit on press 'Enter' no more work

Tags: html, angular, typescript

All example of code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-cegwyu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fenter.directive.ts

When I fill input and press enter on keyboard I got alert. ( try to stackblitz )

But problem is when I fill input and select dropdown then press enter - nothing.

I lose my event I don't know where.... and why?

```
@Directive({ selector: '[entersubmit]' })
export class EnterEventDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('keyup.enter', ['$event'])
  onFormKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    alert('submitted'); //when select from dropdown I lose 
    //but when fill only input this is work good
  }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not correct. After several trials, there is no easy way around. It is not possible to add event listeners on dropdown items as they are generating when dropdown is clicked. The only thing coming to my mind - in the directive - private el: ElementRef, on ngOnInit You could querySelect() dropdown bytton and listen for attribute change. Either with help of ngOnChanges(): void or MutationObserver However those options are not preferable as they lower the performance.

Comment: For now, not important the performance in my case...

Comment: @PavloStepura problem is because I don't have idea how to do it ...